# run threads of class member function in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

As the title says.
The following is my code skeleton.

```
class CLASS
{
public:
    void A();
private:
    DWORD WINAPI B(LPVOID);
};

void CLASS::A()
{
    DWORD (WINAPI CLASS::*thread)(LPVOID) = &CLASS::B;
    ...
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread, &arg, 0, NULL);
    ...
}
```

the function B needs CLASS's member variables.
But I've got an error code when I compiled this.
It's " can't convert argument 3 from 'DWORD (__stdcall CLASS::* )(LPVOID)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' " or something like that.
I don't know if it is the same in the english environment.

can anybody help please?

Answer (score 12):

Seriously, use `std::thread`:

```
class CLASS
{
public:
    void A();
private:
    void B(your args go here);
};

void CLASS::A()
{
    std::thread t(&CLASS::B, this, your args go here);
    // when done
    t.join();
    // or
    t.detach();
}
```

## Explanation

Your code doesn't compile because `CreateThread` is a C API, expecting a non-member C function as a callback. In order to call a non-static member function of a C++ class, the caller needs to know about `this` pointer and how to correctly use it. Since WinAPI clearly doesn't have `this` and doesn't expect a member function pointer, this cannot possibly work. Your compiler catches this and reports it as a type mismatch error.

This is where the `lpParameter` of `CreateThread` comes into play. It allows you to pass `this` through that parameter. However it doesn't change the fact that `CreateThread` doesn't know how to call C++ member functions. Therefore it's your responsibility to wrap it in a static function that will do the member function call:

```
class CLASS
{
public:
    void A();
private:
    DWORD B();
    static DWORD s_B(LPVOID);
};

DWORD CLASS::s_B(LPVOID that) {
    return ((CLASS*)that)->B();
}

void CLASS::A() {
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, s_B, this, 0, NULL);
}
```

This is what @Nawaz does in their answer, except in a slightly more general way.

Even though this approach works, it clearly has downsides:

- It's verbose.
- It's non portable.
- You need to pass your original `args` through different means (e.g. through a member of your class).

`std::thread` already does all that for you.

Comment: +1. Yes, definitely go with std::/boost::thread. Moreover, you don't even need bind: `boost::thread t(&CLASS::B, this, your args if any go here);`. As simple as that.

Answer (score 10):

You've to define your callback function as `static` function if it's member function!

---

## Better design : define a reusable class!

From my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633222/static-thread-function-access-non-static-class-member-in-c/4633237#4633237): (with little modification)

Even better would be to define a *reusable* class with pure virtual function `run()` to be implemented by the derived *thread* classes. Here is how it should be designed:

```
//runnable is reusable class. All thread classes must derive from it! 
class runnable
{
public:
    virtual ~runnable() {}
    static DWORD WINAPI run_thread(LPVOID args)
    {
        runnable *prunnable = static_cast<runnable*>(args);
        return prunnable->run();
    }
 protected:
    virtual DWORD run() = 0; //derived class must implement this!
};

class Thread : public runnable //derived from runnable!
{
public:
    void newthread()
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &runnable::run_thread, this, 0, NULL);
    }
protected:
    DWORD run() //implementing the virtual function!
    {
         /*.....your thread execution code.....*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a template, rather than run-time inheritance. But the general idea is correct.

Comment: @DeadMG : yeah.. that would be a little fast... just didn't come to mind when I wrote this...

Comment: @Nawaz: You should always think CRTP first, and then run-time inheritance.

Comment: @DeadMG : Yup. I realized that now. :-)

Comment: It is a bit old-fashioned and awkward design to have to derive a class and override a function to run a thread. Better use boost::thread or a similar mechanism that accepts a functor as a thread function and does not require deriving anything.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make that member function `static`.

The problem here is that every non-static member function has an implicit `this` parameter and that's in fact what the compiler is trying to tell you - your nin-static member function has signature different from the one you expected.

Also see [this answer to a closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668743/why-does-thread-procedure-should-be-static-or-member-function/3668766#3668766).

Comment: And before the OP starts getting any clever ideas - non-static class member function pointers are *weird*. Not only are the calling conventions different from a simple `func(classname *this, ...)`, the _pointer representation_ is weird - in some cases class member function pointers can end up being 2x the size of a normal function pointer, so don't even think about forcing the cast :)