# How to create threads with Win32 API?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have written a TCP server with Win32 API and C++ but it's single-threaded. Can anyone tell me how would I go about making it multi-threaded? I imagine for every new accepted connection, I'd have to spawn a thread that takes care of it. But I have never had experience with threading in Win32. Can anyone tell me how I would go about threaded programming with Win32 and C++?

Comment: Call `CreateThread()`. This question is too general.

Comment: Note that one-thread-per-socket setups are almost never the right design.  I suggest you look into a setup with a fixed number of threads either using non-blocking sockets or [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Note: eventually, you can use boost::thread library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the documentation of :

- [CreateThread Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx)

And you can also see an example in my answer here:

- [Multithreading in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768294/multithreading-in-c)
- [run threads of class member function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666635/run-threads-of-class-member-function-in-c)