# fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I get the above error message (which I googled and found is something to do with a missing curly brace or something), however, I cannot see where this missing bracket is?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    class Something{


        static DWORD WINAPI thread_func(LPVOID lpParameter)
        {
            thread_data *td = (thread_data*)lpParameter;
            cout << "thread with id = " << td->m_id << endl;
            return 0;
        }


        int main()
        {
            for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
            {
                CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_func, new thread_data(i) , 0, 0);
            }

            int a;

            cin >> a;
        }

        struct thread_data
        {
            int m_id;
            thread_data(int id) : m_id(id) {}
        };

    }
```

Comment: Just curious, why is `main` wrapped in a class ?

Comment: Got the example from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768294/multithreading-in-c

Comment: I thought it had to be wrapped in a class?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C++, the `class` keyword requires a semicolon after the closing brace:

```
class Something {

};  // <-- This semicolon character is missing in your code sample.
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It now says "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals" Im sorry, i'm a Java developer !

Comment: @user1107474 that means, compiler could find the declaration provided in header file (*.h) but linked could not find the definition. `declaration - int Count();` <---you have this somewhere but missing `definition - int Count() { return 5; }`

Answer (score 6):

Your class `Something` needs to have a terminating semicolon.

```
class Something{

}; // missing
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon (`;`) after the closing brace (`}`) of the `class Something` definition

Comment: Thanks, dont suppose you know the linker problem I get now?

Comment: Are you linking agains the WINAPI libraries?

Answer (score 2):

you might have missed

```
#ifdef  ROCKSTAR 

#endif <--- this might be missing
```