# Can I convert a method to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, mingw

I had declared a function and passed as 3 parameter of CreateThread() function but I tried to put this function and related in a class apart, to make code more organizated but I got the following error:

> error: cannot convert 'long unsigned int (MainWindow::*)(void*)' to
>   'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE {aka long unsigned int
>   (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(void*)}' for argument '3' to 'void*
>   CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, SIZE_T, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE,
>   LPVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD)'

```
                                                               ^
```

I guess it's because every first parameter of a method as hidden parameter auto-generated by the compiler which is where `this` pointer gets passed making the function signature mismatch, right?

Is there any way I can make this work?

It does happens in the call from inside a method:

```
   hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, &func, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: By "method" do you mean a class member function? Then it needs to be marked as `static` or it won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [run threads of class member function in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666635/run-threads-of-class-member-function-in-c)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, I mean a member functiono of a class. The problem with `static` is accessing class's properties. On the link pointed out by @captain obvilious seems to have a good design by Nawaz. I'll try it

Comment: Since you're using Qt you'd probably be better off with `QThread`. If you don't want an event loop in your thread, you could use `std::thread`. Either way, there's very little reason to use Win32 threads directly in modern C++ development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which takes a void*.  Use this as parameter and cast it back in function